# Uploading to youtube with eden php and laravel 4?

Tags: php, api, frameworks, youtube

I've been struggling with this for hours now and I still cannot resolve the issue. I am using eden php and laravel 4.

I am trying to simply submit a request for the upload token using the following code:

```
    include('eden.php');
    
    //Requests::register_autoloader();
    $t = 'token_here';
    $key = 'api_key_here';

    $upload = eden('google')->youtube($t, $key)->upload();

    $title = 'Awesome video test';
    $description = 'as mentioned this is a test';
    $category = 'People';
    $keyword = 'testing';
    return $upload->getUploadToken($title, $description, $category, $keyword, 'youtube_username');
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> Undefined variable: ___file
>
> ErrorException
> …/­public/­eden.php54

However any other API request I make works perfectly... I would be forever greatful if you can help me solve this (most likely due to my stupidity) dilema.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**hey can you try my package**

[I port eden to laravel 4 package](https://github.com/taqmaninw/laravel-4-apipack)